# How to use OrientDB fetchPlan to return a SQL Traverse

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

In both Java and SQL I can recurse through a list of Vertices to get all linked nodes.  But I can't seem to get the same result when using fetchPlan.

This returns the correct graph (all nodes linked to the parent but not other parents that share the same child node)

```
traverse out('Dependency') from #33
```

I am looking for a fetch plan that will return the same graph.  Pasted below is a  fetchPlan that is close but pulls in other root nodes and I only want all the children of a single parent.

```
id.getRecord().toJSON("fetchPlan:out_Dependency:6")
```

My DB has 2 Vertices and 1 Edge connecting them. Parent -> Edge -> Child.  A child might be linked to multiple parents but from parent view I only want to see his children not connected Parents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:out_Dependency:2') from #21:0
```

this is what I get:

[image]

as you can see the query returns me only the linked child and not the other parents.

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: thanks for the response, it does give me the child of the parent but it doesn't give the childs children.  Traverse does do this properly.  A parent has a child and that child may have a child.

Comment: But do you want that yhe query returns you the childrens of a specific record or the childrens of all the parents?

Comment: Much like a Java dependency tree I want to see, that springMVC depends on SpringCore which depends on apacheCommons.  But I don't want to see the hundreds of other projects that depend on apacheCommons or Spring.

Comment: A javascript function would be ok for you?

Comment: Sure.  Currently I display the resultset using a javascript recursive function.  If I knew more about orientdbJS I probably could have skipped that step.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you could use this function with the paramenter rid

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var nodes = [];
var previous=[];
var currently=[];
var b=g.command("sql","select from " + rid);
if(b.length>0){
    var vertex=b[0];
    previous.push(vertex);
    nodes.push(vertex);
    do{
        for(i=0;i<previous.length;i++){
            var vertexOut=previous[i];
            var vertices=g.command("sql","select expand(out('Dependency')) from "+ vertexOut.getId());
            for(j=0;j<vertices.length;j++){ 
                currently.push(vertices[j]);
                nodes.push(vertices[j]);
            }
        }
        change();
    }while(previous.length>0);
    return nodes;
}

function change(){
    previous=[];
    for (indice=0;indice<currently.length;indice++)
        previous.push(currently[indice]);
    currently=[];
}
```

Hope it helps